# Strange mesh distortion in render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh

I follow a tutorial to re-build an effect used in [Ghost in the Shell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqvqx6VtjEk). I did every step and it works fine in the viewport but once I switch to cycles, the image just went spiky and crazy:

[image]

Here is the file without baking to keep it light for you to check. It bakes quickly, looks good in viewport but is spiky in the rendered image. Please have a look:

[image]

**Q:** How can get the viewport result when rendering the image?

Comment: Link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqvqx6VtjEk

Comment: Hard to guess, most likely bad displacement settings. Suggest share your file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=0WWGxjga" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/0WWGxjga/)


i added the file without baking to keep it light for you to check..it bake quickly...shows good in viewport but go spiky in render...please have a look

Comment: Subdivision modifier is disabled for viewport rendering

Comment: If you apply the subdivision and bake again, the issue disappears.